# Python BeautifulSoup missing information inside tag how to include information inside the tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from a website.
But when I want to print it I just get the tags back, but with out the information in it.

This is the code:

```
#Imports
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


#URL
my_url = 'https://website.com'
#Opening connection grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
#closing the page
uClient.close()
#Parse html
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
price = page_soup.findAll("div",{"id":"lastTrade"})
print(price)
```

This ist what I get back:

```html
[<div id="lastTrade"> </div>]
```

So does anyone can tell me what i have to change or add so I receive the actual infortmation from inside this tag?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting any results at all? It looks like you are just getting an empty list (== no results for a div with `id=lastTrade`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe loop through your list like this :

```
for res in price:
    print(res.text)
```